# Angular2 selected option in SELECT removed from all other SELECT tags options

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular, angular2-forms

I have several dropdowns, all have the same initial options. 
*(they may be initialized with one value at the beggining).*
I am looking for solution to a case when choosing one option in one dropdown - it will no longer show as an option in the other dropdowns.
I saw this solution in AngularJS and didn't succeed making it work in Angular 2 RC 4:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918935

In addition I saw that pipes are not recommended for filtering as of Angular.io:

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend that you move filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this issue:

**In html:**

```
<select [ngModel]='currValue'
        (change)="update($event.target.value, i, $event.target.options.selectedIndex)"
         name="{{i}}"
         #select>
                <option *ngFor="let currItem of items | distinctValue: selectedList: select.value: i: currValue; let j=index"
                        value="{{currItem}}">{{currItem}}</option>
</select>
```

**In ts:**

```
selectedList: any = [];
```

when changing the selected value of select - push the item into the selectedList and remove the previous selected value of this element from the selectedList so it could be picked again.

**In DistinctValue.pipe.ts:**

```
transform(itemsList: any, filtersList: any, excludeItem: any, row: any, currItem: any) {

  return itemsList.filter(function(option:any) {
      let keepItem: boolean = true;
      let currFilter: number = 0;

      // Check if the option should be filtered
      while ((keepItem) && (currFilter < filtersList.length)) {

        // If option exists in filters list and not this item
        if ( (option.fieldname != currItem.fieldname)
              (option.fieldname != excludeItem.fieldname) &&
              (option.fieldname == filtersList[currFilter].fieldname) ) {
            keepItem = false;
        }

        currFilter++;
      }

      return keepItem;
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you could write a custom filter pipe.

in html:

```
options | optionFilter:optionToRemove
```

js:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'optionFilter'
})
class OptionFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(options, optionToRemove) {
        return options.filter(function(option) {return option.id !== optionToRemove.id)};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a start, but there should be also check for the current value of the element.